# The old church (from Littlewood's Miscellany)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, humor

I’m apparently in that part of the human race that *doesn’t* ‘get’ the following paragraph. If you are in the *other* part, please a) wipe that smirk off your face, b) explain what I’m missing (ideally, preceded by a hint). Thanks!

> *The old church.* Old lady: ‘We have a very old church here, 1913.’ ‘Oh, auntie dear, you mean 1319.’ ‘Not at all, my dear, 1325.’ (This sharply divides the human race.)

Context & credits: The quote above is from the chapter ODDS AND ENDS of the book “Littlewood’s Miscellany,” by John Littlewood and Bela Bollobas. That particular chapter is a collection of brief self-contained anecdotes, observations, puzzles, and random other stuff.  Littlewood does not explicitly state that this particular item is a puzzle, but I think that's a safe bet; at any rate, it puzzles *me*!

I should add that, while Littlewood was an eminent British early 20th century mathematician. Most of the Miscellany, including the chapter from which this quote was taken, is directed at the intelligent layperson.

Comment: It might be important, that -- according to the authors -- this was a chestnut in 1913, quite unknown in 1930, and unknown in 1956, see preceding comment in text.

Comment: I never thought that was a puzzle, just a joke. The humour lies in the fact that it doesn't actually make any sense for someone to turn 1325 into 1913 by first getting six years out and then muddling up the first and second halves of the date (i.e., in the very thing that makes it baffling if you think of it as anything other than a date).

Comment: I don't know if it helps at all, but I find it funnier if I imagine it actually being *told* (perhaps by a stand-up comedian), slightly silly voice for the dear auntie and all.

Comment: Matsmath:  Yes, Google Books shows the parenthetical remark you quote appearing between this and the previous item.  Every _other_ such remark in the chapter clearly applies to the item _preceding_, so I doubt that this one violates the convention (the common "1913" has other possible explanations); but you could be right, thanks!

Comment: er, in case it isn't obvious, "anything other than a date" in my earlier comment was meant to be "anything other than a joke".

Comment: Gareth & Deusovi, thanks.  Something along the lines you suggest is certainly possible, but to me this seems out of character in the context of the items in that chapter.  When Littlewood makes the reader think at all, there is usually an unambiguous "aha" moment waiting at the end of the cogitative rainbow.  I don't feel that here.  [And Gareth I somehow read "joke" as date, perhaps because unlike you I wasn't thinking ahead to the evening:-]

Comment: I wonder by what number of years the old ladies reduce their real age ;)

Comment: @Matsmath, the chestnut/unknown thing is definitely attached to the previous item (about the mongoose) rather than to the "old church" joke; you can tell by the line spacing. user34099, the fact that the said previous item is plainly a joke seems to me sufficient reason not to be surprised if this one is also a joke.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be a puzzle, but instead a joke (although not a very funny one).

Originally, it seems like the old lady had simply transposed the digits, so her niece/nephew attempted to correct her on the year. But then she knew the correct date, so you wonder how she even got from "1325" to "1913" in the first place - it's not an easy mistake to make.

Comment: What about the meaning of "this sharply divides the human race"?  Is the human race sharply divided into those who find the joke funny and those who don't? :)

Comment: @ErickWong, I think that's exactly Littlewood's meaning.

Comment: The best I can make of it is that the old lady knew that the date was 1325; she recalled the "13", but then, in expanding this to a full year number she mistakenly took that 13 to be '13, i.e. 1913, just as we might, these days, equate '13 with 2013.